# has_any performance tanks after 64 values

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a query which was performing really well via an optimization that uses has_any to filter on values in a dynamic object.

Suddenly its performance has tanked, and I noticed that this happens when the list has more than 64 values.

Here are some stats with increasing number of values used in the has_any():

```
limit 10  totalcpu 58s, datascanned 9.1GB
limit 20  totalcpu 63s, datascanned 13.2GB
limit 30  totalcpu 80s, datascanned 17.5GB
limit 40  totalcpu 92s, datascanned 21.8GB
limit 60  totalcpu 124s, datascanned 30.3GB
limit 64  totalcpu 130s,  datascanned 32.1GB
limit 65  totalcpu 12412s, datascanned 930GB
limit 70  totalcpu 12263s, datascanned 868GB
limit 80  totalcpu 13410s, datascanned 1.9TB
```

**Update from 2023-10-20**
The new limit seems to be 2048.
Here are some stats on a different query, using a static dataset:

```
limit 1024: totalcpu 33s, datascanned 5.48gb, peakmem 58mb
limit 2048: totalcpu 1m17s, datascanned 10.7gb, peakmem 104mb
limit 2049: totalcpu 2h58m, datascanned 111.7gb, peakmem 478mb
limit 3072: totalcpu 3h0m46s, datascanned 111.7gb, peakmem 483mb
```

Answer (score 1):

has_any() internally rewrites itself as regex after certain limit (it is 64 values right now, in future it may grow - but still: a limit will exist).
If you find yourself looking for a specific element in dynamic array - you can try set_intersect() function: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/setintersectfunction

Using this function will check:

... | where array_length(set_intersect(source, lookup_array))>0

Comment: Thanks for that info, set_intersect is useful if both sides are sets but in my case left is a 'complex dynamic object' with nested properties.   It would be helpful if the has_any documentation had a perf warning on this (since the degradation in my case is 100x), and if KE returned some sort of warning when this is encountered.

Comment: Interestingly, in some cases this perf degradation occurs with less than 64 values. ClientRequestId: KE.RunQuery;775d5f4d-39a2-474d-9081-ecc78405a97e